# Display pdf file on web with search text functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Can anyone tell, how to display pdf file on web with search text functionality.

Comment: you want to search inside the pdf files?

Comment: yes display pdf file in aspx page having search text functionality.

Comment: ok then, look at my answer below, it should be very easy to implement

Answer (score 2):

If you mean searching inside the pdf files, you can do this:

- download this dll Interop.Cisso.DLL and then add it as a reference
- Create your catalog (you should define a catalog in the indexing service to search inside it) it is done this way: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308202
- finally here is your code for doing the search:

  ```
     DataSet ds = new DataSet("IndexServerResults");
      CissoQueryClass q = new CissoQueryClass();
      CissoUtilClass util = new CissoUtilClass();

      OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

  string query = "";
  if (lstSearchIntegration.SelectedValue == "-1") {
      query = "@all Contains " + txtKeywordOne.Text + " and not #filename *.log";
  } else {
      string operation = "";
      if (lstSearchIntegration.SelectedValue.ToLower == "and") {
          operation = "and";
      } else {
          operation = "or";
      }
      query = "@all Contains " + txtKeywordOne.Text + " " + operation + " " + txtKeywordTwo.Text;

   }

  switch (lstDocType.SelectedValue) {
      case "doc":
          query += " and #filename *.doc";
          break;
      case "pdf":
          query += " and #filename *.pdf";
          break;
      case "ppt":
          query += " and #filename *.ppt";
          break;
      case "pps":
          query += " and #filename *.pps";
          break;
  }

  q.Query = query;
  q.Catalog = "YourCatalogName";
  q.SortBy = "rank[d]";
  q.Columns = "DocAppName,rank, path, size, FileName,VPath, Create";

  q.MaxRecords = 1000;
      util.AddScopeToQuery(q, "YourFolder", "deep");
  object obj = q.CreateRecordset("nonsequential");
  da.Fill(ds, obj, "IndexServerResults");
  DataTable mydt = new DataTable();
  mydt = ds.Tables[0];
  ```

Please note that:

1. I am using and/or operations for smarter search
2. I am searching inside doc,pdf,ppt and pps
3. I am excluding log files from search

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest [Aspose.PDF](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) but it costs money